# Renci SSH .NET SFTP - creating file while no free space on SFTP server hangs forever

Tags: c#, .net, sftp

I'm using Renci SSH .NET SFTP library for uploading / downloading files to SFTP server.

Recently I've got unexpected situation - file upload hanged and stayed in this state for several hours - file on the server was created, but with the size of 0 bytes.

Later, server administratior admitted that they were running out of free space on the server, so it looks like that was the reason.

But my question is - why SFTP client didn't throw any exception, not timeout, nothing?

My code for uploading file to SFTP looks like this:

```
            try
            {
                using (var client = new SftpClient(account.Host, account.Username, new[] { privateKey }))
                using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(localFilePath))
                {
                    client.Connect();

                    if (!client.Exists($"/{account.DirectoryPath}/{ftpDirectory}"))
                        client.CreateDirectory($"/{account.DirectoryPath}/{ftpDirectory}");

                    client.UploadFile(fileStream, ftpFilePath);
                    client.Disconnect();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // exception handling
            }
```

How to prevent against such cases in the future?

Renci SFTPClient by default has 30s connection timeout, but it was not fired on this case.
I was thinking about checking the free space before uploading file, but I see that library does not support that kind of function as well.

So, what are my options? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: It seems like this should be a bug report for the developers of the library you're using.

Comment: Or bug in the server. Did you test any commandline/GUI client in the same scenario?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I think that was because I didn't set OperationTimeout parameter to specific value - it comes as infinity by detault. I think that was the reason.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like reason of the problem was that `OperationTimeout` parameter in `SftpClient` was not set - by default it comes as infinity.

Comment: I do not think so.

Comment: Well, I know what helped me but if you know it better....